# What is the "general contract" of a method

Tags: java

I'm looking at the the java docs for `DataInputStream` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html

I'm looking to see what its methods do so I look at the descriptions of `readBoolean()` , `readByte()`, `readChar()`etc.

The descriptions are all something along the lines of:

> See the general contract of the readBoolean method of DataInput.

And in the extended explanation.

```
public final boolean readBoolean()
                          throws IOException
See the general contract of the readBoolean method of DataInput.
Bytes for this operation are read from the contained input stream.

Specified by:
readBoolean in interface DataInput

Returns:
the boolean value read.

Throws:
EOFException - if this input stream has reached the end.
IOException - the stream has been closed and the contained input stream does not support reading after close, or another I/O error occurs.

See Also:
FilterInputStream.in
```

Where can I "see" the general contracts of these methods and what is a general contract of a method?

Comment: Building on @JonSkeet 's answer, "General contract" often describes documentation attached to an interface method describing in a _general_ way, how an implementation of the method should behave or, documentation of a base class method that describes how an override of that method should behave.  When somebody writes a specific implementation or an override, they can just say, "see the general contract" instead of replicating all of that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that the documentation of [`DataInput.readBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readBoolean--) contains more detail. In particular, that documentation states:

> Reads one input byte and returns `true` if that byte is nonzero, `false` if that byte is zero. This method is suitable for reading the byte written by the `writeBoolean` method of interface `DataOutput`.

So you should expect `DataInputStream.readBoolean` to behave that way.

Answer (score 1):

A *general* contract of a method in a base class is one that must be the basis of the contracts of the method in all extending classes. It is *general* in that it applies generally to the whole genre of the base class and all its derived classes. Regardless of other terms derived classes may add to the method's contract, it must always keep the general contract.

An *explicit* general contract is one that's given in the method documentation for the base class.